LINQ query where clause in list
I am trying to limit the data returned via a repository using the where clause based on a list of values.
I have a PurchaseOrders entity where I want to return all purchase orders that have an OrderStatus of either "Open" or "Invoiced".
I am passing in those parameters as a string array named purchaseOrderParams.orderStatus.
These values will change based on the user selection in the client app.
If I was writing an SQL it would look like:
SELECT ALL FROM PurchaseOrders WHERE OrderStaus IN ('Open', 'Invoiced')

Now I understand that I need to convert the string array of purchaseOrderParams.orderStatus to a list:
List<string> orderStatusList = new(purchaseOrderParams.OrderStatus);

And I am trying to pass it to the query:
var query = context.PurchaseOrders
            .Include(x => x.Supplier)
            .AsQueryable();
query = query.Where(x => x.OrderStatus!.Contains(orderStatusList));

My where clause appears to be failing.

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'char'

Any ideas?
I have tried to adapt a bunch of different types of examples that include contains and any but I can't figure it out.

You have to flip the values: list.Contains(value)

It should be orderStatusList.Contains(x.OrderStatus) that checks whether the status value exists in the order status list.
var query = context.PurchaseOrders
            .Include(x => x.Supplier)
            .AsQueryable();
query = query.Where(x => orderStatusList.Contains(x.OrderStatus));


Thanks mate. I feel like an idiot.  It's so obvious.
